# Loop adding values from the keyboard?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I want to create a script that'd work as a basic graphic interface for postgres database. I'm using psycopg2 library. I have a problem with a function that'd create tables.

So far I have a function:

```
def create_table(dbname,user,password,table_name,column_name,column_type,constraint):
   conn = connect(dbname, user, password)
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE %s(%s %s %s)""" % (table_name,column_name,column_type,constraint))
```

And I'm able to create a table with one column. I'd like to be able to create a table with as many columns as the user wants to ("table_name","column"name","column_type","constraint" are taken from the keyboard). I don't know how to construct such function, though. I predict it needs some kind of a loop.

To clarify, I want something like that:

in the command line it should print:

table name: (user writes, name is given)

column name:

column type:

constraint:

**It's already working in my script**

But then, I'd like to have just:

column name (again):

column type (again):

constraint (again):

So more columns could be added.

Comment: You need `for` or `while` - these are pretty simple python concepts, so I'd suggest reading up on them and coming back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a loop that asks the user whether to continue each time, where in each iteration, information for a new column, i.e. the column name, type and constraint, is appended to a list of columns.

After the user chooses to stop adding columns, you have to construct your query. Possibly with, in the new [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings) syntax, `'CREATE TABLE {} ({})'.format(table_name, columns)`. I'm not going to spell out in code how to construct `columns`, but you could first create a string for each column, again using string formatting, and then [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them with commas. In the end, `columns` should look something like this: "customer_id INTEGER UNIQUE, customer_name VARCHAR(50), phone CHAR(8)".

There are probably less error-prone ways to accomplish this. You could check that each type and constraint, for instance, is valid.